# Can the Selective Spell metamagic feat be used to exclude a swarm from targeting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, metamagic, spellcasting, swarm

I'm researching the attack spells available to druids. [Creeping Doom](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/creeping-doom/) looks very useful for some situations, but it seems like it doesn't combine well with other spells like [Flame Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-strike) and [Fire Storm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fire-storm) since you'll quickly destroy your own swarms.

Can a druid use [Selective Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/selective-spell-metamagic/) to mitigate this by excluding the swarms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Most probably no

While [Swarms](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Swarm_Subtype) "act" as a single creature, they are not "treated" as a single creature, except when the subtype mandates it: HD, HP, initiative, speed, AC and Saves.

As an exception to all these things where the swarm is treated as if it was a single creature, swarms are immune to any spell that targets a specific number of creatures. While I have no proof that this is true, I think this ability is meant to represent the fact that the swarm, despite having a single AC, HP pool, and so on is still made of individuals and affecting a bunch of those will not stop the whole swarm.

While there are no rules specifically about this rare situation, I infer that the swarm should also not be immune to any spell that avoids targeting a specific number of creatures, as a Selective spell does: you have spared a few chosen individuals, which are Diminutive and therefore not big enough to be a threat (the smallest Centipede monster is Tiny), but the bulk of the swarm has been damaged.

Comment: Swarms are treated as a single creature for most effects; this answer needs to back up the implied assertion that Selective Spell is an exception.

Comment: @KRyan do you think the reasoning holds? Of course I'm into Rules-As-Interpreted territory, but I don't think the manuals ever give a RAW answer to this very peculiar occurrence.

Comment: I do not think it does, no. I agree that there probably is no more to be found in the rules on the subject, but to my mind anything that considers individual elements of a swarm rather than the singular swarm creature is a mistake. That isn’t necessarily to say that mistakes weren’t made—after all, the swarm subtype wholesale is largely one mistake after another.

Comment: Well, it's a mistake they started.

Comment: My point is that I don’t think this is one particular mistake they did make—I’m just acknowledging that they made many and it wouldn’t be *that* surprising if they did. But I remain unconvinced by the evidence before me that they actually did.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, but probably not the way you are thinking

The [selective spell feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/selective-spell-metamagic/) allows you:

> When casting a selective spell with an area effect and a duration of instantaneous, you can **choose a number of targets in the area** equal to the ability score modifier used to determine bonus spells of the same type... **These targets** are excluded from the effects of your spell.

Emphasis added.

A creature with the swarm subtype:

> is **immune to any spell or effect that targets a specific number of creatures** (including single-target spells such as disintegrate), with the exception of mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms) if the swarm has an Intelligence score and a hive mind.

This means that:

- A swarm is immune to any spell that targets a specific number of creatures.  It can still be targetted by such a spell, but it will suffer no effects of said spell
- This does not apply if the spell gains the [mind-affecting] descriptor and the swarm gains an intelligence score "and a hive mind". (Centipedes typically lack both, so I will not further address this)
- It doesn't matter if a spell has multiple effects, some targetting only a limited number of creatures, some targeting everything in an area: any spell (or other effect) that targets for any purpose a specific number of creatures will see *none* of its effects affect a swarm
- A selective spell targets a specific number of creatures, even though the base spell it would have been without metamagic feats wouldn't have done so.

And, in conjunction:

- A selective spell ***never*** affects any swarm, whether you want to exclude them or not

Comment: I’m not 100% certain this works out here—you choose a number of targets to exclude, which isn’t necessarily the same as choosing a number of targets to include, which means the spell may well still just be an area effect for any creatures not chosen with Selective Spell.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by a difference between targeting creatures to exclude or include.  It seems to me that the swarm traits just care about whether a spell targets some creatures, not what it targets those creatures for.  I assume you are suggesting there is a chain of logic that links being targetted to be excluded from an effect and technically not being targetted in a sort of non-hearsay hearsay exception sort of way, but if so I am not seeing it. I can approach this instead/in addition in a manner addressing that, I think, but it would be helpful to understand better the objection.